# Bounding box of S-57 ENC chart?

Tags: bbox, s-57

Is there some standard way of obtaining bounding box of an S-57 chart, e.g., for one downloaded from https://www.charts.noaa.gov/InteractiveCatalog/nrnc.shtml?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Each layer could have a different bounding box.

GDAL has [support for S-57](https://gdal.org/drivers/vector/s57.html) and its [ogrinfo](https://gdal.org/programs/ogrinfo.html) tool can show you the bounding box per layer.

For example (with grep to filter out the relevant lines:

```
$ ogrinfo -so -al US5SC25M.000 | grep -E '(Layer name|Extent)'
Layer name: DSID
Layer name: ADMARE
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
Layer name: ACHARE
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
Layer name: BCNLAT
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
Layer name: BCNSPP
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
Layer name: BRIDGE
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
Layer name: BOYLAT
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
Layer name: BOYSAW
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
Layer name: BOYSPP
Extent: (-79.902793, 32.503085) - (-79.357460, 32.807348)
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way to obtain the real map polygons **which sometimes consist of more than 4 points** is to visit the [NOAA charts interactive map](https://www.charts.noaa.gov/InteractiveCatalog/nrnc.shtml) which displays them.

[image: NOAA maps]

In the network console you will find a request to https://www.charts.noaa.gov/InteractiveCatalog/data/enc.json which consists of all maps including the coordinates which you can postprocess accordingly.

[image: Network console]

Answer (score 0):

1. Download the S-57 ENC file **A.000**.
2. Convert the S-57 ENC file **A.000** to **shapefiles** with ogr2ogr:

ogr2ogr -skipfailures -where "OGR_GEOMETRY='POLYGON' or OGR_GEOMETRY='MULTIPOLYGON'" -oo SPLIT_MULTIPOINT=ON -oo RETURN_LINKAGES=ON -oo LNAM_REFS=ON  -mapFieldType StringList=String,IntegerList=String "**OUTPUT DIRECTORY**" **A.000**

3. You will get many **shapefiles** in "**OUTPUT DIRECTORY**"  and one of them is also  **M_COVR.shp**, which is, by definiton, **"A geographical area that describes the coverage and extent of spatial objects"**. This is what you are looking for!